# Help with arrowmechanism

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

[image]

```
void Rotate()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 correctpos = (mousePos - (Vector2)transform.position).normalized;
        transform.right = correctpos;
    }
```

The above is for fire point rotating towards the cursor.

The below is for the shooting

```
 void Shoot()
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
                {
                    if (hasEneryGun == true)
                    { 
                        GameObject newbullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, playerbulletFirePoint.position, playerbulletFirePoint.rotation);
                        newbullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity =  playerbulletFirePoint.rotation * Vector2.right * launchForce;
                    }
                }
            }
```

*The Problem is I want to instantiate bullets toward the mouse, but it will always go right*

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: every instruction we'd need to follow to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project — including how you've set up "firepoint" in your scene/inspector, whether it has child or parent objects that have colliders, etc.

Comment: the fire point is a empty object is a child to another empty object is a child to player prefab and there are no colliders attached to empty object

Comment: the Mousemechanism is a separate script and is attached to an empty weapon game object and the weapon sprites and fire point is attached to the weapon empty gameObject.